# SSO Authentication Using LDAP in Java Web Application

Tags: java

I have a simple java web application and have to authenticate it using sso using LDAP.I have searched a lot but could not find any clear documentation on it.If anyone have suggestions or idea about it Please share with a sample code.Thanks in advance!

Comment: LDAP is only a user store to authenticate the users and store their data. SSO is usually enabled by other means using LDAP as backend. You may search for SSO protocols like Kerberos (commonly used with Active Directory), SAML SSO or OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

try Waffle (Windows Authentication Framework).
tomcat example: https://github.com/Waffle/waffle/blob/master/Docs/tomcat/TomcatSingleSignOnValve.md